# Is there anyway to add a widget and set its geometry on a qvboxlayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

When a qboxlayout is created, any widget added to it would in its layout, and I create a widget and set its geomoetry, then add to the widget, the geometry doesn't work.
This is code:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(centralWidget);
QWidget *widget1 = new QWidget();
QWidget *widget2 = new QWidget();
layout->addWidget(widget1);
layout->addWidget(widget2);
QWidget *widget3 = new QWidget();
widget3->setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 100);
layout->addWidget(widget3);
```

This is what I want to realize
[image]

Comment: Either you control the widget's geometry *or* the layout does -- that's the reason layouts exist.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @G.M. How could I realize it by another way?

Comment: @opsky, I'm not sure of your question, but just by looking at the image: instead of adding (constructing  / setting the parent for) a widget on click, you can simply add the widget to your `QBoxLayout` variable and call `hide()` / `show()` when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question exactly, but if you want to define to size of your widget in the layout, you can maybe try `widget3->setFixedSize(..)`. This should set both the maximum and minimum size of the widget.

However, the position will still be managed by the layout.

To have a hand on the position, you can use the `Qt::Alignment` flags in the `addWidget()` function.

Otherwise, if you really want to use the geometry directly, you should *not* add the widget to the layout, but simply create the `widget3` with the `centralWidget` as parent.